# Google VR samples build fails with nullpointerexception

Tags: android, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

Just cloned the google-vr sdk, but I'm not able to built the samples. gradle --stacktrace fails with

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Exception is: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
>     ...

Windows 10

Java_Home and path points to version 1.8

Gradle is at version 4.10

Android setup in general is ok, as I work quite often in Android Studio on other projects without problems.

I'm out of ideas what the cause could be. Any tip to solve this is welcome.

Comment: Did you tried it? " Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I gave up trying to get this thing working and moved on.